# Search contact name containing x

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception, android-contacts, contactscontract

Building a device that connects to Bluetooth and retrieves contact names/numbers matching a certain "name", for example, if I search for "A - " and I have the following contacts in my phone:

```
[0] "A - Dad "
[1] "A - Mom"
[2] "A - Grandmother"
[3] "FirendA "
```

It returns the following list:

```
[0]
    [0] A - Dad
    [1] +33600000000
[1]
    [0] A - Mom
    [1] +33611111111
[2]
    [0] A - Grandmother
    [1] +33722222222
```

So this function should return an array containing the contact name and the contact number (only starting with +336 or +337 (mobile)) inside an array of all contacts matched.
But so far with the code I tried it returns me a which returns me a null pointer exception:

```
public List<List<String>> getContacts(String name) {
        List<List<String>> out = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID },
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER, null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String currentName = cursor.getString(1);
            String currentId = cursor.getString(2);
            Cursor cursor2 = getContentResolver()
                    .query(android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            new String[] {
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME },
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?",
                            new String[] { currentId }, null);
            while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
                String currentNumber = cursor2.getString(0);
                if(isMobilePhone(currentNumber)) {
                    List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
                    tmp.add(currentName);
                    tmp.add(currentNumber);
                    out.add(tmp);
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        return out;
    }
```

And I retrieve the array like this:

```
        List<List<String>> contacts = myServiceBinder.getContacts(txt);
        for(List<String> con : contacts) {
            String[] array = new String[con.size()];
            con.toArray(array); // fill the array
            Log.wtf("test",array[0]+" : "+array[1]);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your'e trying to do. maybe clarifying your question and intentions can help me (and others) understand what your'e aiming for.

Comment: Do you understand now ?

Comment: No, I cant even understand what your function is supposed to do with the contact names and all that.

Comment: Ok Can't make more clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is over complicated.

1. As you can notice in your projection, you can access the contact ID and display-name directly from the `Phones` table
2. You can iterate the Phones table directly, no need to query the Contacts table at all
3. You can use `SQLITE`'s `LIKE` operator to search your keyword in the `DISPLAY_NAME` field
4. Instead of an `Array` of size 2, you can use `Pair` in your list

Here's code:

```
public List<Pair<String, String>> getContacts(String name) {

    List<Pair<String, String>> results = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] projection = new String[] { Phone.CONTACT_ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER };
    String selection = Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '%" + name + "%'";
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        long contactId = cur.getLong(0);
        String name = cur.getString(1);
        String phone = cur.getString(2);

        Log.d("Contacts", "found: " + contactId + ", " + name + ", " + phone);

        results.add(Pair.create(name, phone));
    }
    cur.close();
}
```

Comment: I just saw that the question was missing détail to only get the contact if one of his number start with +336 or +337 (mobile)  ans store only that number. But i think i can make it work i will test when I get back from school